# Print a stack of animation frames from Matlab's figure

Tags: animation, printing, export, matlab-figure

I have a large collection of images stacked together within one Matlab figure (for example animation frames) and I want to print it on my printer. I can't print it directly from my figure window because Matlab's printing function allows me to print the whole figure on a single sheet of paper. Then I tried to export it in some image format and to print it via external software. I exported my figure at `.jpeg` format, the resulting image was very small and I don't know how to make it bigger because there are no scaling options (if I'm not mistaken, the only possibility to make it larger is to scale figure window before exporting, in such a way the largest possible jpeg file will also be very little). My question is how to print such tall images from Matlab figure's window in separated sheets of paper so that the division of image on subsheets can be specified by user? If it isn't possible directly from Matlab, what is the simplest way to do it via external software?

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

- Depending on how you generate these images, you could use the `print` function to print each as it is created.
- You can set the size of the image before you export it to jpeg using `set(gcf,'Position',[0,0,560,900])